# Do not understand how loop is determining how many asterisks to print

Tags: java

I am a beginner at learning Java. I have stumbled upon a problem that I can not figure out. How is the loop in the code determining how many asterisk to print out. I keep looking at this part of the code..

```
asterisk < myArray[counter]
```

Could someone please explain in the simplest of terms how this works, because every time I think of the counter, I see it as nothing but the index that it is pointing to at that time in the loop.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = {12, 7, 9, 11, 23};

        System.out.println("Value Distribution");

        //Start of outer for loop
        for( int counter = 0; counter < myArray.length; counter++){

            //Start of inner for loop
            for( int asterisk = 0; asterisk < myArray[counter]; asterisk++)

                System.out.print("*");

            System.out.println();

        }//End of outer for loop
```

Comment: The problem with "explain how this works" questions is that we can't know what you actually do understand - we could easily waste time explaining stuff that you do understand, and not actually address the specific problem you are having. Step through the code with a debugger, read a tutorial about for loops.

Comment: Hint: Indentation is not important in Java. In other words, `System.out.println();` is not inside the inner loop

Comment: You are correct, `counter` is literally nothing but the loop index of the outer loop.  What about that is confusing you?

Comment: I am not understanding how the code knows how many asterisks to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put

```
asterisk < myArray[counter]
```

Means that it's checking whether amount of asterisks is less than the value from myArray[counter].

So when you have
`counter = 0`
You also have
myArray[counter] = 12.

Which means in your inner for loop, it will print asterisks until `asterisk` is no longer lesser than 12. Thus, going from 0-11 will print 12 asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

The line you have highlighted is testing that the loop index `asterisk` is less than the value in the `myArray` array an index `counter`.

Since `counter` is the index variable for the first loop, this will increase each time the outer loop executes.

So, in the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop repeats until `asterisk` is greater than or equal to 12 (the value of myArray at index 0).

In the second iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop repeats until `asterisk` is greater than or equal to 7 (the value of myArray at index 1).

And so on.

This is why the program outputs the following:

```
************
*******
*********
***********
***********************
```

Answer (score 0):

In words...

- For each value **X** in `{12, 7, 9, 11, 23}`

  - Print `*` **X** times
- Print new line

> every time i think of the counter, i see it as nothing but the index that it is pointing to at that time in the loop

Correct. `counter` is the position of the `myArray`. You need that to access the value at `myArray[counter]` to determine how many asterisks to print.

However, the same result could be acheived without `counter` by using an [enhanced for-loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

```
for (int howManyAsterisks : myArray) {
    for (int a = 0; a < howManyAsterisks; a++) System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, the first loop runs to the length of the array `'myArray'` which in this case equals to 5. Then the second loop runs every time to length of the individual items in the `'myArray'` (i.e. 12 times for the first time, 7 for the second time and so on).

Hope this helps you.